# Update with more than 1 variable

Tags: sql-server, variables

I tried to use more than 1 variable in the same query but I received an error about column... do you have an idea?

```
Declare @query nvarchar(max)
set @query = 'contact'

Declare @var2 nvarchar(max)
set @var2 = 'value'

declare @strSql nvarchar(2000)
set @strSql = 'UPDATE Inventaire.dbo.test SET Inventaire.dbo.test.' + @query + ' = ' + @Var2 + ' WHERE Inventaire.dbo.test.nDeviceID = 1'

exec sp_executesql @strSql
```

Error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'value'.

Answer (score 1):

You need single quotes (`'`) around the value:

```
Declare @query nvarchar(max)
set @query = 'contact'
Declare @var2 nvarchar(max)
set @var2 = 'value'


declare @strSql nvarchar(2000)
set @strSql = 'UPDATE Inventaire.dbo.test SET Inventaire.dbo.test.' + @query + ' = ''' + @Var2 + ''' WHERE Inventaire.dbo.test.nDeviceID = 1'
exec sp_executesql @strSql
```

You need to double them up to make the server know that you are trying to use a literal `'`.

With the single quotes, you have `'value'`. Without them, you have `value`, which means you are referring to a column named `value`.

Comment: @AntoineCrué are you sure you made my changes? That should be impossible if you have all of the correct quotation marks.

Comment: Hi Ed Cottrell, I tried with your query but it changed nothing : Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'value'.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solaution : ''' + @Var2 + ''' 
it's 3 '

Thanks for your help :)